# Scrape Javascript OnClick button with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am struggling with getting the email address from this URL: `https://www.iolproperty.co.za/view-property.jsp?PID=2000026825`
that is only seenable after clicking on the button "Show email address". However, when I try to click and get the email address that I want to scrape, I get " Message: element click intercepted:"
Not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance!

```
contact_email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[@id="viewagmail"]/a/@href'))).click()
```

Comment: Are you sure you share correct code? `'//span[@id="viewagmail"]/a/@href'` should not work as it returns `@href` not WebElement. Please update your question with exact code

Comment: @saraherceg `element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH))` isn't that Python code? You have tagged javascript??

Comment: @JaSON, I have tried both without @href but still cannot get to the email..even with `invisibility_of_element_located`

Comment: Can you share exact exception log?

Comment: `contact_email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Show email address"]'))).click()`
eventually just ends up in  `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:`
@JaSON

Comment: This code line is senseless since you're trying to wait for button to disappear to click it. Share exception that you got with your initial code line

Comment: `contact_email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Show email address"]'))).click()`
I see that when I use this line it does click on it and I can see the email but it does not save the actual email, I get this `selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewcont('emailadd',15609774);return false;" style="float:left;display:inline;">...</a> is not clickable at point (679, 506).` @JaSON

Comment: Try with this line before clicking `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('footcont').setAttribute('hidden', true)")`

Comment: I am still unable to catch the actual email, here is what I have:
`self.driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('footcont').setAttribute('hidden', true)")
        contact_email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Show email address"]'))).click()` @JaSON

Comment: `contact_email = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//a[text()="Show email address"]')))     contact_email.click()`

Comment: hmm it still returns None when I check after the click @JaSON

Comment: How you tried to "check"? Show code

Comment: I did contact_email.text which is definitely not correct, since I want to store the email. Do I need a new xpath once the button is clicked to actually get the text of email? @JaSON

Comment: yes. try `'//span[@id="viewagmail" and @style="display: block;"]/a`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried time sleep if DOM elements are not stable/page hasn't loaded?
Also, remove href from xpath

```
(By.XPATH, '//span[@id="viewagmail"]/a')
```

Then just get mail with getText() or getAttribute("href") using that xpath

Or if it happens after clicking on button and trying to get email address, try using wait until

```
invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[text()='Show email address']'))
```

Comment: I have tried the `invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//a[text()='Show email address']'))` but it does not seem to click the button to get the email, and I am not sure why. It runs out in timeout..@ble

Comment: Have you first clicked on '//a[text()='Show email address']'. Then waited for it to 'be invisible' and then tried to catch email by getting text from '//span[@id="viewagmail"]/a'?